# Simple Excel Scripts For Ruby-Watir?

Tags: ruby

Can Anyone Explain How to pass different Values(Valid,Invalid,Empty) For Username And Password fields Using Microsoft Excel  ?

1. Like I need to get Values from Excelsheet
2. I need Script in Ruby

I have Tried to refer But There is no proper Documentation for Excel Scripts..

Comment: http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a gem like roo. I am not sure where it is hosted nowadays, but either of these links should help:

- http://roo.rubyforge.org/
- http://rubygems.org/gems/roo

Answer (score 0):

"roo" gem is the answer for your query.
It is simple to use and very easy to understand

This gem allows you to access the content of

```
* Open-office spreadsheets (.ods)
* Excel spreadsheets (.xls)
* Google (online) spreadsheets
* Excel’s new file format .xlsx
```

This link is very helpful

```
http://roo.rubyforge.org/ 

http://roo.rubyforge.org/rdoc/index.html
```